# Interacting with CentOS on Hyper V, whilst connected to a VPN

Tags: centos, connection, vpn, hyper-v

So I have a CentOS, running inside Hyper V. It boots up fine and, with both a Default Switch Network Card and an "External" Network card running and configured, I can ssh to Centos from the Host, and Centos can get to the Internet. All good.

It all changes however if I connect to my Work VPN from home using Cisco Anyconnect on the Host over my Wifi connection. After that, I can no longer ssh into Centos, and of course, I need to.

How can I alter my setup so I can ssh back into Centos from the Host, whilst the Host is connected to my work VPN? Has anyone successfully done this?

Thanks.